# Speeding up and improving directory listing from windows Servers?

Tags: snow-leopard, windows, network, finder

When I connect to windows servers (called PC-servers in OS X) getting the list of files in a directory is *really* slow (20-30s) in comparison to using a windows machine (<1s). Sometimes the files in a directory even disappear for a while! The network is not slow - copying files goes at 1Mbyte/s.

What can I do to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Finder then try with another file manager or try run a ls in the terminal. Let us know if you are experiencing the same kind of delays using the command line.

Some good alternative file manager are [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/) and [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/). Try both.

Comment: I can't install mc without root access, so I could only try muCommander. Directory listings are blazing fast indeed, but filetransfers are really slow now (136k/s vs 1Mb/s in finder....).

Comment: ...and muCommander can only copy files, not open them for editing. Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to speed up the directory listing by mounting shares via the command line, like this:

```
mount -t smbfs //user@server/sharename share
```

Where share is a directory in my home directory.

Somehow this is faster than mounting in the finder. Or is it ADmitMac slowing stuff down?